# How to set up internal browser for Aptana on Linux

Tags: php, linux, aptana

I downloaded the Aptana_Studio_Setup_Linux.zip package, unpacked it and run ./AptanaStudio. It starts fine, but reports one problem:

*The embedded browser widget for this editor cannot be created. It is either not available for your operating system or the system needs to be configured in order to support embedded browser.*

After that, it opens the "Welcome page" in external browser (Mozilla), but when I click on a link to install PHP support it does not open the destination target. No wonder, because the link is in format: com.aptana....etc. I.e. written in reverse. I assume such links only work with internal browser.

If I look into details, I get these error messages:

```
No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3400)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.<init>(BrowserViewer.java:224)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.WebBrowserEditor.createPartControl(WebBrowserEditor.java:78)
at com.aptana.ide.intro.browser.CoreBrowserEditor.createPartControl(CoreBrowserEditor.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:596)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:372)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:566)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:290)
```

etc. I hope this is enough.

I tried to set the env. variable:

```
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla/
```

However, it only changes the error message to:

```
No more handles [NS_InitEmbedding /usr/lib/mozilla/ error -2147221164]
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [NS_InitEmbedding /usr/lib/mozilla/ error -2147221164]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3400)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:225)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.<init>(BrowserViewer.java:224)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.WebBrowserEditor.createPartControl(WebBrowserEditor.java:78)
at com.aptana.ide.intro.browser.CoreBrowserEditor.createPartControl(CoreBrowserEditor.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:596)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:372)
```

For start I really want to have PHP working, but I'd also like to fix the whole internal browser issue in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** getting internal browser to work is NOT required in order to get PHP support in Aptana. Just install PHP support from **Help**, **Software updates** menu.

Answer (score 6):

I happened to come across this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/xmind/5SjPTy0MmEo/PbPi0OGzqPwJ

Which advised running:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

should solve the problem. It worked for me so I figured I'd share here.

FWIW, I ended up here while trying to get the Play! Framework working on Ubuntu 13.04. using the Scala-IDE. So far, everything seems to be working...

Comment: Thanks man! It solved the issue for me. Also I was unable to see colors when I wanted to commit changes, which was quite annoying.

Comment: That seemed to do it for me. Running Ubuntu 16.x in an Oracle Virtualbox VM under windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install XULRunner from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XULRunner), and point MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to that directory.

Comment: Tried, and apparently it didn't work. What should be the EXACT steps to do that?

Comment: @MilanBabuškov: 1. install xulrunner using your package manager (I tested both versions 1.9.2 and 2.0, both worked); 2. `export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner` <-- make sure it's there first, with a `whereis xulrunner`.

Comment: After setting the MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME I've got: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
/home/lna/Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/232/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3740.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

After installing xulrunner you need to set this:

```
MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install XULRunner then edit the eclipse.ini.

After installing xulrunner, adding the following line in the eclipse.ini solved the problem of "No more handles" issue.

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/eclipse/xulrunner/

I am using eclipse 3.63 and ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

If this is the problem I think you're having, just installing Firefox 2 (alongside FF3) should fix the issue. It happens because Aptana can only use FF2 at the moment. Hopefully they'll fix this soon.

If you're on Ubuntu, it's really just a case of:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-2
```

Naturally, the process will vary on different distributions.

Comment: I already have Firefox 2 installed, it's the default browser in Slackware 12.1.