# Eclipse 'Unhandled loop exception' on Team > Commit

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I recently started using git with the egit plugin in eclipse, and I thought I had everything working. I cloned a remote repository to my machine, then made a change to a file, and went to commit the change via selecting the file in the project, and going to `Team > Commit...`. As soon as I do, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled event loop exception
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1826)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:96)
    ...
    (output abbreviated)
```

I am fully willing to accept that this is a bug of sorts (even though I thought this was working earlier today), but I am hoping someone may have encountered this problem once before.

Any insights? Even if it is only who I should file the bug against? I can provide any additional details. I should also point out that things work fine if I commit through the git repository view.

Comment: Maybe this is linked to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344270 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the particular git workflow is creating a SWT Browser component that is having trouble loading on your particular OS + Windowing system + mozilla library version combination.  There is a bit of black magic that has to go on to make sure you get the right configuration to allow the SWT browser to work with your embedded mozilla renderer.  You can get detailed information on the [SWT FAQ page here.](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howdetectmozilla)

Also there are many other posts on this site that talk about how to resolve the dreaded "NO MORE HANDLES" problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214272/how-to-set-up-internal-browser-for-aptana-on-linux).

Comment: Hmmm, I couldn't manage to get things working, but this does seem to be the right course of action; I'll just have to fiddle around some more. Thanks :)