# pentaho data integration Exception in table output

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio

I am getting this type of exception in pentaho  data integration

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
```

Comment: Is this about code that you have written? If so, please include your source code in the question.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: in spoon ide when iam trying to Right-click on the Table Output step, and select Visualize -> Analyzer. iam getting this exception please help me  to solve. thanks

Comment: could it not be a ulimit restriction? Try increasing ulimit -n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a possibility of version conflict between your browser and the ide. You can have a look at the below links. I found these on searching.

[SWT Browser & Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695271/swt-browser-eclipse)

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21271865