# Aptana 3, GitHub can clone but can't commit

Tags: github, clone, aptana

I am very new to GitHub and I am using Aptana 3 on Ubuntu.  I was able to clone a repository for GitHub by using file/import/Git Repository

When I added files to the local repo and I tried to commit I get this error.

```
Unhandled event loop exception
No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
```

How do I commit to GitHub in Aptana?

Answer (score 2):

The SO answer "[How to set up internal browser for Aptana on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214272/how-to-set-up-internal-browser-for-aptana-on-linux)" lists some solution.
Check also your version of Aptana vs. JDK (32 or 64 bits): "[Barking Up the Wrong Tree](http://www.raditha.com/blog/archives/barking-up-the-wrong-tree..html)"

More recently (December 2012, [Bruno Carlin](http://aerdhyl.eu/about-me.html)), this issue can also be linked to the **version of Xulrunner in Arch LinuX repositories** (see "[Aptana Studio/Eclipse and Xulrunner](http://aerdhyl.eu/blog/2011/12/Aptana-eclipse-and-xulrunner.html) ")

> The solution is that Aptana Studio cannot work with the version of Xulrunner in Arch LinuX repositories because it is too recent.
>
> To solve this problem, I had to install xulrunner 1.9.2 from AUR:

```
yaourt -S xulrunner192
```

> Finally, I put

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.2
```

> at the end of the AptanaStudio3.ini file in the Aptana Studio folder. For the package in the Arch Linux repositories, this file is `/usr/share/aptana/AptanaStudio3.ini`.