# Aptana error when committing to git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana 3.0.7 and whenever I try to commit changes to git repository, I receive this error:

> Unhandled event loop exception No more handles
>   [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons']
>   (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
>     /home/amir/Desktop/Aptana Studio
>   3.0.5/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/226/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3659.so:
>   libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>     no swt-mozilla-gtk in java.library.path
>     /tmp/swtlib-32/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3659.so: libxpcom.so: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory     Can't load library:
>   /tmp/swtlib-32/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so )

followed by this message:

> An SWT error has occurred, you are recommended to exit workbench , ...
>   etc.

I downloaded aptana 3.0.9 but same error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [old thread](http://blog.aplikacja.info/2009/10/libxpcom-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/) (2009) mentioned the possibility to link (symlink) to the missing libraries.
But I would recommend first to [check the version of xulrunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697685/aptana-3-github-can-clone-but-cant-commit/8698445#8698445).

> The solution is that Aptana Studio cannot work with the version of Xulrunner in Arch LinuX repositories because it is too recent.

In other words, it doesn't depend on Aptana version itself, but rather on the version of one external component ([XULrunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner)).

Comment: Thanks VonC, it was the XULrunner