# Aptana internal web browser error, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, aptana, chromium, xulrunner

I am running elementary 0.2 (Ubuntu 12.04 but with a different desktop environment) and I installed Aptana studio. Everything is fine aprt from I can't get the internal web browser to work.

When I open the Aptana Studio start page I get the an error that says "we were unable to load the Chromium browser. Please check the documentation for details on possible workarounds/fixes. The message contains a link but you have to have an @aptana address to access it. Clicking on details after closing the error gives me the following which if very similar to [How to set up internal browser for Aptana on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214272/how-to-set-up-internal-browser-for-aptana-on-linux) but I have tried `MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/xulrunner` and it did not work.

> No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path
>   (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Mozilla.java:1826)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:687)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.(Browser.java:99)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.(BrowserViewer.java:225)
>     at
>   com.aptana.portal.ui.internal.BrowserViewerWrapper.createSWTBrowserViewer(BrowserViewerWrapper.java:26)
>     at
>   com.aptana.portal.ui.browser.AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.createBrowserViewer(AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.java:216)
>     at
>   com.aptana.portal.ui.browser.AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.createPartControl(AbstractPortalBrowserEditor.java:112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)    at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2942)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2756)
>     at
>   com.aptana.portal.ui.internal.Portal$1.runInUIThread(Portal.java:227)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at com.aptana.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just found it was a missing dependency for thought I'd post this anyway just in case someone else had the same problem. To fix type

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Comment: Also fixed for me on Ubuntu 13.04 with Aptana Studio Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.4.1, installed libwebkitgtk 3.0 instead:
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-0

Comment: Actually, it complained about missing _Chromimum_ browser; but this fixed the issue.

Comment: @Simon yeah same here - Ubuntu 16.04